# Нарушается раскраска ячейки datagrid при выравнивании по left/right/center

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть дата грид.
Пишем код на раскраску ячеек.
По умолчанию все нормально раскрашивается вся ячейка.
Если выравнивать по правой стороне то раскрашивается только текст.
код.
Два варианта. Без выравния и с выравниванием по правой стороне.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="LightGray" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>                    


<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="LightGray" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```

[image: Результат:]

1. Как сделать так чтобы закрашивалась вся ячейка?
2. Ну и для полного счастья, как убрать белый интервал между строками. Чтобы
   закрашенная ячейка была сплошным цветом.

Comment: 1. Почему вы применяете стиль к `TextBlock`? 2. Почему вы позиционируете контрол, а не контент в контроле?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Да, я понимаю что вероятно нужно ячейку раскрашивать но никак не могу найти что прописать чтобы применялось к ячейке.

Comment: Ну вы работаете с чем? С ячейкой или ее контентом? Если с ячейкой, то применяйте стиль к ячейке (`DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle`), тогда тип стиля меняйте на `DataGridCell`, а всякие `TextBlock.Background` меняете на простой `Background`, тогда у вас будет изменен стиль ячейки. Если брать ваш стиль, то вы работаете с контентом, не затрагивая стиль ячейки, ок, тогда, раз вы работаете именно с `TextBlock`, то меняйте положение текста, а не самого контрола, за это отвечает `TextAlignment`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ TextAlignment помог. спасибо.

Comment: Касательно 2-го вопроса, то тут надо сделать 2 шага. 1. `<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="None">` - это уберет черные полосы, но не уберет отступы. 2. Переписать стиль **всех** ячеек, дописав туда `<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>`. (`<DataGrid.CellStyle><Style TargetType="DataGridCell"><Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/> (закрывашки)`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  спасибо попробую.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ По второму вопросу тоже все получилось. Спасибо.